# Invisible Cursor in NeoVim-GTK

Tags: ubuntu-mate, neovim

Running NeoVim with the GTK interface, the cursor/insertion point is invisible. How can I get a visible cursor?

In insert mode there's no indication at all of where I'm typing:

[image: Screenshot of a NeoVim-GTK window in insert mode, without a cursor]

In normal mode it's almost as bad: moving the cursor over a visible character very slightly changes its form or shifts it a pixel sideways or something, but it's really hard to see. Here it's on the second ‘g’ in “wiggle”:

[image: Screenshot of some text in normal mode, in which the two ‘g’s in “wiggle” look pretty much identical, but the spacing seems a bit off, as though the second one has nudged slightly towards the first ‘g’ and away from the ‘l’]

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS. NeoVim was installed from the `neovim` package, which is version 0.4.4-3. Its GTK interface was installed with the following, and reports itself as v0.2.0-76-gc036492:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:daa84/neovim-gtk.git
$ cd neovim-gtk
$ sudo apt install cargo
$ cargo build --release
$ sudo make install
```

Invoked simply as `nvim-gtk`. I have moved my `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` files and `.vim` directory elsewhere, so this is happening without anything in my personal config.

Any suggestions for how to see what I'm typing gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: I would vote for "off-topic". You are building NeoVim from the latest upstream sources, which makes it impossible to reproduce. Why are you not just open an issue on https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues? This might haben on Ubuntu, but I doubt, that it is an Ubuntu only issue.

Comment: The question's here because I want to run NeoVim with the GTK interface on Ubuntu, by any means. The above just describes what I did (though I am actually using NeoVim installed with apt, as I stated). NeoVim probably wouldn't want a bug report on something specific to the GTK interface. I'll report a bug on neovim-gtk if it indeed turns out to be a bug, not just me doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing what was suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have neovim-gtk so I can't test this; I am just trying to help.

There is [a plugin](https://github.com/daa84/neovim-gtk/tree/master/runtime/plugin) to change cursor blinking, perhaps that can be helpful.

Related? https://github.com/daa84/neovim-gtk/issues/99

`NVIM_GTK_DOUBLE_BUFFER` can help?

Comment: The plugin just wraps an existing `rpcnotify()` call, which still doesn't work. And nor does the double buffer thing (as per a recent comment at that link). However, that does seem to be the relevant bug report, which I'd failed to find myself, so I'll accept this answer as the most useful.